# weighted means by group and column

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, sapply

I wish to obtain weighted means by group for each of several (actually about 60) columns.  This question is very similar to: [repeatedly applying ave for computing group means in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145403/repeatedly-applying-ave-for-computing-group-means-in-a-data-frame) just asked.

I have come up with two ways to obtain the weighted means so far:

1. use a separate `sapply` statement for each column
2. place an `sapply` statement inside a `for-loop`

However, I feel there must be a way to insert an `apply` statement inside the `sapply` statement or vice versa, thereby eliminating the `for-loop`.  I have tried numerous permutations without success.  I also looked at the `sweep` function.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
df <- read.table(text= "
          region    state  county  weights y1980  y1990  y2000
             1        1       1       10     100    200     50
             1        1       2        5      50    100    200
             1        1       3      120    1000    500    250
             1        1       4        2      25    100    400
             1        1       4       15     125    150    200

             2        2       1        1      10     50    150
             2        2       2       10      10     10    200
             2        2       2       40      40    100     30
             2        2       3       20     100    100     10
", header=TRUE, na.strings=NA)

# add a group variable to the data set

group <- paste(df$region, '_', df$state, '_', df$county, sep = "")
df    <- data.frame(group, df)

# obtain weighted averages for y1980, y1990 and y2000 
# one column at a time using one sapply per column

sapply(split(df, df$group), function(x) weighted.mean(x$y1980, w = x$weights))
sapply(split(df, df$group), function(x) weighted.mean(x$y1990, w = x$weights))
sapply(split(df, df$group), function(x) weighted.mean(x$y2000, w = x$weights))

# obtain weighted average for y1980, y1990 and y2000
# one column at a time using a for-loop

y <- matrix(NA, nrow=7, ncol=3)
group.b <- df[!duplicated(df$group), 1]

for(i in 6:8) { 

    y[,(i-5)] <- sapply(split(df[,c(1:5,i)], df$group), function(x) weighted.mean(x[,6], w = x$weights))

}

# add weighted averages to the original data set

y2 <- data.frame(group.b, y)
colnames(y2) <- c('group','ave1980','ave1990','ave2000')
y2

y3 <- merge(df, y2, by=c('group'), all = TRUE)
y3
```

Sorry for all of my questions lately, and thank you for any advice.

EDITED to show `y3`

```
  group region state county weights y1980 y1990 y2000   ave1980  ave1990  ave2000
1 1_1_1      1     1      1      10   100   200    50  100.0000 200.0000  50.0000
2 1_1_2      1     1      2       5    50   100   200   50.0000 100.0000 200.0000
3 1_1_3      1     1      3     120  1000   500   250 1000.0000 500.0000 250.0000
4 1_1_4      1     1      4       2    25   100   400  113.2353 144.1176 223.5294
5 1_1_4      1     1      4      15   125   150   200  113.2353 144.1176 223.5294
6 2_2_1      2     2      1       1    10    50   150   10.0000  50.0000 150.0000
7 2_2_2      2     2      2      10    10    10   200   34.0000  82.0000  64.0000
8 2_2_2      2     2      2      40    40   100    30   34.0000  82.0000  64.0000
9 2_2_3      2     2      3      20   100   100    10  100.0000 100.0000  10.0000
```

Comment: Keep the questions coming, but I (we?) would appreciate it, if you provided some dummy data and demonstrate how the desired result would look like.

Comment: Sorry.  I have added the contents of the data set 'y3' to my post.  The dummy data are in the data set 'df' and the code seems to run on my computer.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to use package data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt2 <- dt[,lapply(.SD,weighted.mean,w=weights),by=list(region,state,county)]
print(dt2)

   region state county   weights     y1980    y1990    y2000
1:      1     1      1  10.00000  100.0000 200.0000  50.0000
2:      1     1      2   5.00000   50.0000 100.0000 200.0000
3:      1     1      3 120.00000 1000.0000 500.0000 250.0000
4:      1     1      4  13.47059  113.2353 144.1176 223.5294
5:      2     2      1   1.00000   10.0000  50.0000 150.0000
6:      2     2      2  34.00000   34.0000  82.0000  64.0000
7:      2     2      3  20.00000  100.0000 100.0000  10.0000
```

If you want you can `merge` with the original data.table afterwards:

```
merge(dt,dt2,by=c("region","state","county"))

   region state county weights.x y1980.x y1990.x y2000.x weights.y   y1980.y  y1990.y  y2000.y
1:      1     1      1        10     100     200      50  10.00000  100.0000 200.0000  50.0000
2:      1     1      2         5      50     100     200   5.00000   50.0000 100.0000 200.0000
3:      1     1      3       120    1000     500     250 120.00000 1000.0000 500.0000 250.0000
4:      1     1      4         2      25     100     400  13.47059  113.2353 144.1176 223.5294
5:      1     1      4        15     125     150     200  13.47059  113.2353 144.1176 223.5294
6:      2     2      1         1      10      50     150   1.00000   10.0000  50.0000 150.0000
7:      2     2      2        10      10      10     200  34.00000   34.0000  82.0000  64.0000
8:      2     2      2        40      40     100      30  34.00000   34.0000  82.0000  64.0000
9:      2     2      3        20     100     100      10  20.00000  100.0000 100.0000  10.0000
```

Comment: How would one restrict doing the weighed.mean on just a subset of the columns here, such as `list(y1980, y1990)` only?

Comment: @FooBar Use `.SDcols`. See `help("data.table")`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to nest `sapply` inside `apply` to obtain weighted averages by group and column without using an explicit `for-loop`.  Below I provide the data set, the `apply` statement and an explanation of how the `apply` statement works.

Here is the data set from the original post:

```
df <- read.table(text= "
          region    state  county  weights y1980  y1990  y2000
             1        1       1       10     100    200     50
             1        1       2        5      50    100    200
             1        1       3      120    1000    500    250
             1        1       4        2      25    100    400
             1        1       4       15     125    150    200

             2        2       1        1      10     50    150
             2        2       2       10      10     10    200
             2        2       2       40      40    100     30
             2        2       3       20     100    100     10
", header=TRUE, na.strings=NA)

# add a group variable to the data set

group <- paste(df$region, '_', df$state, '_', df$county, sep = "")
df    <- data.frame(group, df)
```

Here is the `apply` / `sapply` code to obtain the desired weighted means.

```
apply(df[,6:ncol(df)], 2, function(x) {sapply(split(data.frame(df[,1:5], x), df$group), function(y) weighted.mean(y[,6], w = y$weights))})
```

Here is an explanation of the above `apply` / `sapply` statement:

1. Note that the `apply` statement selects columns 6 through 8 of `df` one at a time.
2. For each of those three columns I create a new data frame combining that individual column with the first five columns of `df`.
3. Then I split each of those new 6-column data frames into chunks by the grouping variable `df$group`.
4. Once a data frame of six columns has been split into its individual chunks I calculate the weighted mean for the last column (the 6th column) of each chunk.

Here is the result:

```
          y1980    y1990    y2000
1_1_1  100.0000 200.0000  50.0000
1_1_2   50.0000 100.0000 200.0000
1_1_3 1000.0000 500.0000 250.0000
1_1_4  113.2353 144.1176 223.5294
2_2_1   10.0000  50.0000 150.0000
2_2_2   34.0000  82.0000  64.0000
2_2_3  100.0000 100.0000  10.0000
```

Using package `data.table` is nice, but until I become more familiar with its syntax and how that syntax differs from the syntax of `data.frame` I thought it would be good to know how to use `apply` and `sapply` to do the same thing.  Now I can use both approaches, plus the approaches in the original post, to check one against the others and learn more about all of them.

Comment: This solution is a bit convoluted and its performance is probably not very good (but I haven't benchmarked). You are basically trying to reinvent the wheel. If you want nice syntax you should look into package `plyr`. I demonstrated the `data.table` solution because it's much faster with big datasets. All split-apply-combine functions allow you to specify several grouping variables.

Comment: I just benchmarked both solutions.  Yours was about 2.5 times faster.  Thank you for the suggestions.