# Calculate a series of weighted means in R for groups with different weightings

Tags: r, mean, with-statement, weighted-average

I have the following dataset (simple version of my actual data), 'data', and would like to calculate weighted means for variables x1 and x2, using weightings w1 and w2 respectively, split up into two groups (groups determined by the variable n).

```
data <- data.frame(n = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), x1 = c(4,5,4,7,5,5), x2 = c(7,10,9,NaN,11,12), w1 = c(0,1,1,1,1,1), w2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1))
```

I'm trying to do it using with() but get an error when I run this:

```
with(data, aggregate(x = list(x1=x1, x2=x2), by = list(n = n), FUN = weighted.mean, w = list(w1 = w1,w2 = w2)))
```

On the otherhand, if weights aren't specified it works, but in this case default level weights are used (i.e. same as using FUN=mean).

```
with(data, aggregate(x = list(x1=x1, x2=x2), by = list(n = n), FUN = weighted.mean))
```

This question is similar to [weighted means by group and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145859/weighted-means-by-group-and-column), except that my question includes different weightings for different columns. I tried using a data table but it runs into the same weighting errors as with().
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(x1=weighted.mean(x1, w1), x2=weighted.mean(x2, w2)) , by = n]
```

Or as @thelatemail commented, we can use `Map` to loop over "x's", corresponding "w's" columns  and call with a single `weighted.mean`

```
setDT(data)[, Map(weighted.mean, list(x1,x2), list(w1,w2)), by = n]
```

If there are many "x" and "w" columns, we can use `grep` to get the column names, `mget` to return the values inside the `Map`

```
setDT(data)[,  Map(weighted.mean, mget(grep('x', names(data), 
    value=TRUE)), mget(grep('w', names(data), value=TRUE))), by = n]
```

Comment: `data[, Map(weighted.mean, list(x1,x2), list(w1,w2)), by=n]` to save having to type the function multiple times.

Comment: @thelatemail That is very nice option.  I was also thinking `Map` in a base R context  but didn't get it right.  Wouldn't this go as a separate post.

Comment: it's essentially the same as your code, just feel free to edit it in if you like. I don't need the imaginary internet points :-)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(n) %>% 
  summarise(x1 = weighted.mean(x1, w1), x2 = weighted.mean(x2, w2))
```